# Copy equations from word in Mathml format

Tags: ms-word, ckeditor, mathml

I have created a large number of mathematical equations in Word 2013 using the in-built equation editor. I need to enter these equations into a browser based editor(CKEditor with fmath plugin) which supports mathml.

Is there a way to copy these equations from word and paste them as mathml in the online editor?

Any other solution( which will result in me not having to type every single equation again) besides copy/paste would also be very helpful.

Comment: Can you export the equations into *some* format?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. To clarify, I was trying to use the standard copy/paste. I did not export the equations into any other format

Comment: Well you will clearly have to convert them first?

Comment: I am very new to this. Can you specify which format should i convert to and how?

Comment: MathML maybe?........

Comment: well that is what the question is. How do i export them as mathml

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have probably used the new (as from Word 2007) Equation Tools. Then the conversion is simple. The old equation editor is still available, but you need to take extra measures to use it (Insert → Object → Microsoft Equation 3.0), so probably and hopefully you haven’t used it.

When you copy an equation created using Equation Tools and paste it in an editor, such as Notepad, it should get automatically transferred in MathML format.

If this does not happen (and you get just some characters in the equation instead), check Equation Options. You can open them in the Equation Tools, Design tab; click on the very small icon in the lower right corner of the Tools group:

[image]

Then you’ll see the item “When copying an equation,”, with two alternatives; select “Copy MathML to the clipboard as plain text”.

Comment: This will be great for html5 as new browser's will support MathML natively.  Can anyone recommend a polyfill for older browser's?

Comment: Note in my version of Office the current latest (2016 Pro) the icon to click is in the bottom right of Conversions group

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2019 + MathType 7.4.8.0 you can simply right click on the formula and chose Equation Object > Convert to Office Math
[image: Screenshot from Word]