# Copy a math formula from Word DocX to CkEditor

Tags: math, ckeditor, latex, formula, mathjax

Basically I have to copy many math formulas from a docx document in CKEditor.
I tried in so many ways but I can not find a solution.

Using Word 2013 I can to copy the formula as a linear text getting a result like this

```
z_(i,j)=100-((x_(i,j)-µ_j ))/s_j 10
```

Starting from this [math formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqw4M.jpg)

In CKEditor I use the mathjax plugin to insert laTeX formulas.

How can I do this???
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mathjax documentation on their website:

> MathJax allows you to include mathematics in your web pages, either
>   using LaTeX, MathML, or AsciiMath notation, and the mathematics will
>   be processed using javascript to produce HTML, SVG or MathML equations
>   for viewing in any modern browser.

The format of the math formula you provided is AsciiMath. You should probably read the documentation on it:

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/asciimath.html

According to the plugin for ckeditor website however (http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax), it only says it supports TeX formulas, there is no mention of AsciiMath, so you might have to actually modify the plugin or just convert your equations to TeX format, it's a pretty easy syntax.

The syntax can be found here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: FYI Office's linear syntax might look similar to asciimath but is considerably different (much more complex/complete). The most reliable export would be MathML, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23737937, but as your answer points out, CKEditor only handles TeX input.