# How to determine the display mode of MathML obtained from a Math Equation in a Microsoft Office document

Tags: ms-word, mathml

I'm displaying following `Microsoft Office Math` equation in display mode in my `Microsoft WORD`. But when I get it's `MathML` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23737937/1232087)) and use it in following HTML file, the equation displays in `inline` mode.

**Question**: Is this bug in Microsoft Math feature. Or what else could be a reason? I think the `MathML` obtained from MS WORD should have the attribute `display="block"` in the `<math...>` tag but it doesn't. Why?

**Math equation in WORD document**

[image]

**MathML obtained from above Math equation in WORD document**:

```
<math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"><mrow><munderover><mo stretchy="false">∑</mo><mrow><mi>n</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn></mrow><mrow><mn>100</mn></mrow></munderover><mrow><msub><mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow></msub></mrow></mrow></math>
```

**HTML Page containing above MathML (obtained from MATH equation in MS WORD)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MathJax TeX to MathML Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"><mrow><munderover><mo stretchy="false">∑</mo><mrow><mi>n</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn></mrow><mrow><mn>100</mn></mrow></munderover><mrow><msub><mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow></msub></mrow></mrow></math>
</body>
</html>
```

**Display view of the above HTML page**

[image]

Comment: I doubt if anyone except Microsoft will be able to provide a definitive answer to the "why" question. We could speculate that it's because in the OOXML the difference in the two layouts is marked by the presence/absence of an oMathPara element **outside** the oPara element and the developers decided not to try to translate that aspect of the display into mathml. But in any case you could use Word's File->Feedback->Uservoice mechanism to suggest a change.

Answer (score 0):

The `<moverunder>` *should* render that as you see it in Word ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/munderover) ).  What browser is rendering the MathML that way when part of an HTML page? Are you using a rendering library (e.g., [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) ) or just letting the browser render it? As it stands, despite being part of the HTML5 spec, MathML still isn’t as widely supported in most browsers as we’d all like. I suspect it may render even *worse* in another browser (if that is a concern).